# Which book should I use to learn Mathematical Analysis 2?

Tags: analysis, education, book-recommendation

I've studied all about metric spaces which is the heart of Mathematical Analysis I, and now i'm about to take the second course of Analysis,which is Mathematical Analysis II and I'm sure you clever mathematicians could recommend me a good book about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rudin maybe?$\,$

Comment: How much is "all about metric spaces"? I doubt you've studied everything that metric spaces have to offer…

Comment: Ask your instructor.

Comment: We don't know what Mathematical Analysis II is at your school.  Why don't you find out the specific topics that will be offered in the course, then ask which books are best for those?

Comment: haha that's right Patrick Stevens.Sometimes they lie zahbaz :( .Here the topics D_S: 1.-Derivation of functions of a variable.   2.-The integral of Riemann-Stieltjes    3.-Sequences and Series of functions  4.-Derivation of function of several variables.